# Open SharePoint form in dialog box on button click

Tags: 2013, modal-dialog

I need to open a SharePoint form from an image button but in a modal dialog box.
Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using following JavaScript.

```
function openDialog(){
    var pageUrl = "your form url";
    var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 700, height: 600};
    SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

Comment: This one worked..But I need to reload the page after saving..cause as of know is is not reloading automatically

Comment: Can I reload a particular page on button click?

Comment: not the  same page...but I need to reload another page on button click

Comment: You mean parent page?

Answer (score 1):

Make a reference to SP15ModalDialog.js on your page, then you can do stuff like

```
<span class="addNew" onclick="openInDialog(870,850,true,true,false,&#39;https://...myPage.aspx?IsDlg=1&#39;)">label</span>
```

See https://gist.github.com/javierguerrero/5249652dea3d389727e0 for details

You can append  &IsDlg=1 to the end of the link to hide the ribbon and navigation bars

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default dialog options on a list or library...

List / Library Settings > Advanced Settings > Dialogs

[image]